# error in pragma exception_init() Statement ignored in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting the error at line 7 (see the code below) which is specified by 10g as :

> `"Statement ignored"`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
create or replace trigger demo1_bifer
    BEFORE INSERT ON demo1 
    FOR EACH ROW 
     declare
         lock_id number;
         resource_busy exception;
         pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(resource_busy,-54);
     begin
         lock_id := dbms_utility.get_hash_value(to_char(:new.x),0,1024);
         if (dbms_lock.request( id => lock_id,lockmode => dbms_lock.x_mode, timeout => 0, release_on_commmit => TRUE) not in (0,4))
         then raise resource_busy;
         end if;
     end;
    /
```

Comment: Just tried it out and I get `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'REQUEST'`. The types look OK though (integer, integer, integer, Boolean). Before we go any further though, is this the same error you are seeing? It's not related to the `pragma exception_init`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. The error I am getting is "Statement ignored" and not PLS-00306. I am using oracle 10g Express Edition. I don't know the reason I am getting this error. Well, if its not related to pragma exception_init then could you please specify to what the error is related to?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the **full** details of all errors relating to this trigger, not just the first one.  Enter `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER demo1_bifer` in SQL*Plus to see all of the errors for this trigger.  There are plenty of reasons why the PL/SQL compiler may choose to ignore a statement, and the next error below `Statement ignored` should tell you why.  Please also bear in mind that the line numbers start counting from the `declare` line, so line 7 is the line starting `if (dbms_lock.request...`.

Comment: @Mukund: PL/SQL compilation errors typically end with 'Statement ignored'. It's the rest of the stack that we need to see.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped `commit` in the parameter name `release_on_commmit`.  Delete one of the three `m`s.

On my system (Oracle 11g XE) I also got an error `PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_LOCK' must be declared`.  To fix this I needed to grant `EXECUTE` on `DBMS_LOCK` to the user I was creating the trigger as.

Comment: @ Luke Woodward. Well,Thanks for that!! I changed it but I am still getting this error in 10g. Is it the case that pragma exception_init() is only supported  in 11g and above editions ???

Comment: @Mukund: nope, [`pragma exception_init` is supported in 10gR1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems015.htm).  Besides, as I pointed out to you in my comment on the question, line 7 is not the `pragma exception_init` line.